# How to work Drag-and-drop for nested array in useFieldArray

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, use-ref, react-beautiful-dnd

I am trying to implement the drag-n-drop feature on a nested array of inputs. I am using `react-beautiful-dnd` and `react-hook-form` libraries: `useFieldArray` hook to manage the form and `useController` hook for controlled input.

The problem I am facing is when i try to reorder any child input, change happens in the last item only. here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/watch-usewatch-calc-forked-t5ltk2?file=/src/nestedFieldArray.js).

To reproduce the issue, you need to add at least 2 top-level inputs along with 2 nested inputs for each of those. Next try to reorder the nested inputs of the 1st top-level item. As a result, child inputs of the 2nd item would change their positions, while the initially dragged inputs would revert back to their original position. [image: see GIF]

I tried to pass `ref` to nested inputs and used `useImperativeHandle` hook to expose `move` method of `useFieldArray` hook from child component to reorder. But everytime only the last child gets reordered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I was using the same ref for my nested field array to store reorder child function therefore when appending a new nested child field array, it was overriding the reorder function and only moving items belonging to the last nested field array.

To solve this, I had to pass a function instead of `ref` to the nested fields which creates different `ref` for each

```
function Parent () {
  const childrenRef = useRef({});
  const setReorder = useCallback(
  (index, reorderCallback) => {
    childrenRef.current[index] = reorderCallback;
  },
  [childrenRef]
 );
  ...

  return (
   <Child
     setReorder={setReorder}
   />
 )
}

function Child ({ setReorder, nestIndex }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    setReorder(`child-${nestIndex}`, (from, to) => {
      move(from, to);
    });
  }, [nestIndex, setReorder, move]);
}
```

Here is the working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/watch-usewatch-calc-forked-5vrcsk?file=/src/fieldArray.js)